# Can one develop an app combining NativeScript and Pure Android

Tags: android, nativescript

I am interested to know if an Android developer can make use of NativeScript and also work directly in the android application. (In the past I worked with Angular 1.x and Typescript, so I am wondering if NativeScript can impact the speed of developing along with Android)

Answer (score 2):

as the [Chapter 6 - Accessing Native APIs](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-6) of the tutorials shown, one can access the Andoird APIs directly and thus benefit from prior work with Android, yes.

Also, your knowledge about Angular and Typescript would be beneficial, but your should be aware of the transformation towards Angular 4.

What you cannot do is generating an "app skeleton" with NativeScript and then continue by working on the generated Android code. If you want to do pure Android development you're certainly better off with Android Studio and Kotlin.

Does this help you with your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you Markus. Also for letting me know more about the latest Angular. :)

Comment: You can also take your pre-existing Android with Java project and include NativeScript in it. So half your project could be developed with Java while the other half TypeScript. https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/06/legacy-android-java-nativescript-angular/

Comment: Can we establish back and forth communication between Java and NativeScript code? Like we can do in Kotlin vs JAVA.

Comment: @AshishM yes, you can for sure! Even though I want to mentaion that the comparison to Kotlin/Java is a bit unfair. As bot complie to the same bytecode and run in the same (Dalvik/Java) VM, there is not really a back and forth in that case ;-)

Comment: @Markus can you tell me how we can send or pass information from Native Android(Java) code to NativeScript code? We are trying to extend existing java based android app with nativescript.